# When using a WAN, which state will appear on a Geolocation Scan?

Tags: wireless-networking, ip-address, wan, geolocation

Let's say I work for a coffee shop chain and their WAN is routed out of Florida.  If my coffee shop is in NJ, will my IP address appear as NJ or FL?

Answer (score 1):

Your WAN IP address will appear as if it's coming from Florida. You could verify this easily with a tool like [this](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/network-location/) or [this](http://aruljohn.com/track.pl).

Note that a website may also try to do geolocation with HTML5, in which case (if you're on a laptop) your actual location may be revealed (accomplished by your browser scanning the Wi-Fi networks around you and using a database like Skyhook or Google Location services). There's a demo of this functionality over at [HTML5 Demos](http://html5demos.com/geo).